# Why do I have two upload buttons on a laravel blade page?

Tags: html, css, laravel

I'm unable to resolve an issue where I'm seeing two upload buttons on a page.

Laravel Blade File Snippet:

```
<div class="col col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-lable">Image</label>
            <div class="file-group">
                <label class="btn btn-primary btn-square" for="select-file">Select</label>
                <input id="select-file" type="file" name="image" class="file-control">
                @if(!empty($entity->imageThumbUrl))
                    <br>
                    <a target="_blank" href="{{$entity->imagePreviewUrl}}">
                        <img src="{{$entity->imageThumbUrl}}" style="width: 200px;" alt="">
                    </a>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Screenshot of the two buttons with HTML shown]

If I remove the button style from the label and apply it to the input I am left with this:

[image]

Comment: maybe 'select' is just a label which is clickable?

Comment: Do you mean a label being styled as a button? Thanks

Comment: Well, that's what `<label class="btn btn-primary btn-square"` does. It applies the Bootstrap button styling to your label, so it looks like one. And, because it's got a `for` attribute, it triggers the same thing clicking on the actual `input` does.

Comment: If I remove style from the label I am left with the text 'Submit', if I then apply the button style to the Input I am left with the Choose File 'box/button' on top of a button which includes the text 'no file selected'. I can't seem to win with this.

Comment: I've updated my question showing the results if I remove the style from the label and apply it to the Input.

Comment: Not quite sure what you were expecting.  You have a label styled to look like a button, next to a file input field, which always has its own button.  A trick with nicely formatting a file input field is to make the label look like a button then set the file input to opacity 0 which makes it hidden.  You then need a bit of javascript if you want to show the name of the file that was selected.

Comment: @JTheBiker Tell us what you're *trying* to accomplish. You have a label, and a file field. Are you trying to make a fully custom looking upload field?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, busy weekend. I want to upload an image and show a preview of that image. I don't necessarily need to see the file name. I've been trying the suggestions but not I don't yet have it working, I'm sorry to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two labels for the same input. You also have "button" classes on the second input label. It'll therefore be styled like a button.

Wrong classes used:  `<label class="btn btn-primary btn-square" for="select-file">Select</label>`

Use different CSS classes. If you are using bootstrap, look at the documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/input-group/#custom-file-input

You probably want something like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</div>
```